# Bundle Install not working; mini_racer can't find v8

Tags: rubygems, bundler

I'm having issues with bundle install running. it seems that mini_racer can't find v8 on my system. I'm not sure what to do. I've uninstall and reinstalled multiple times. Here is the output.

```
    /Users/gregg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:89:in `run': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Ext::BuildError)

    /Users/gregg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lpthread... yes
checking for main() in -lobjc... yes
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling mini_racer_extension.cc
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
mini_racer_extension.cc:4:10: fatal error: 'include/v8.h' file not found
#include <include/v8.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [mini_racer_extension.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2
```

Comment: Just specify a different version or use the github option (`git: 'https://github.com/discourse/mini_racer.git'`).

Answer (score -2):

**Add this line to your application's Gemfile:**

```
gem 'mini_racer'
```

**And then execute:**

```
$ bundle install
```

---

**Or install it yourself as:**

```
$ gem install mini_racer
```

**Then try :**

```
 $ bundle update
```